# Pocket door stuck issue

Tags: doors

I saw a YouTube video < [https://youtu.be/_GiYoeOKJOA?si=OER_IR4xOC4gfhyD>](https://youtu.be/_GiYoeOKJOA?si=OER_IR4xOC4gfhyD%3E) that shows how to unstuck a pocket door.

However when I looked into the top of the pocket door I see the sliding wheels seem to be slanted. How do I straighten it?  I do not want to pry/damanage the existing molding. [image]

Input appreciated.

Comment: Hard to know from one pic. Do the other wheels look like that one, or do they have bearings?

Comment: Hi I could not see the other wheel(s) but I assume they re the same.  I had no problem sliding the door ever until early this week.

Comment: Also, these wheels do not have bearings.

Comment: The reason I ask is because part of me thinks this wheel had bearings and they’re now gone, which means the wheels need replacing.

Comment: Thanks Aloysius.  Looks like I have to remove the top and side moldings to take out the door and replace them.

Comment: TYpically when pocket doors are trimmed, the side jambs are set first and the head piece is set last. That way, with some detective work, if the door was trimmed that way, it should be able to be determined which side needs to come of to release the wheels from the top of the door. When it is released the door should drop down a bit and come out at an angle out of the opening, since the one side of the head filler is no longer in the way as well. The head piece SHOULD be the only piece that needs to be removed.

Comment: Thank you Jack.  I will keep that in mind.